# При использовании Facebook API PHP SDK возникает Fatal Error: Class 'FacebookAds\Api' not found

Tags: php, api, facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Всем привет! Я установил библиотеку через composer для работы с Facebook API для PHP, выполняя пример кода, который описан в официальной документации:

```
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
    use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
    use FacebookAds\Api;
    use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

    $access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
    $app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>';
    $app_id = '<APP_ID>';
    $id = '<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>';

    $api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
    $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

    $fields = array(
    );
    $params = array(
      'special_ad_category' => 'NONE',
      'name' => 'My First Campaign',
      'objective' => 'PAGE_LIKES',
      'status' => 'PAUSED',
    );
    echo json_encode((new AdAccount($id))->createCampaign(
      $fields,
      $params
    )->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Получают в ответ:

`Fatal error: Class 'FacebookAds\Api' not found in /var/www/u0000001/data/www/test.ru/fbad.php on line 15`

То есть ошибка в этой строке:

```
$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
```

Почему? Что не так? (токен, аккаунт id, app id и app secret естественно указаны)

Comment: Покажите ваш композер файл

Comment: @Alpha {
    "require": {
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7"
    }
}

Comment: Проблема в подключении файла `FacebookAds\Api`;

Comment: У вас проблема настройки Composer. Не сделано `composer install` или что в этом направлении. Это не проблема SDK Facebook.